# Java PDF Generation iText Alternative

Tags: pdf-generation

I am brand new to pdf generation or rendering. I am working on a application to replace iText(coz of change in license) and create kind of a RESTful endpoints using any Java related PDF APIs. The library should be able to convert images and.., others to PDF.

- Read/fill the data from PDF programmatically and also merge.
- Also, if we can host it ourselves that would be the best choice.
  Could you please provide some insight into this?

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) from Apache. As I suppose you are using Java when coming from iText.

It allows you to

- create new PDF documents
- manipulate existing documents
- merge two or more existing PDFs into one
- extract content from documents

Two months ago [PDFBox 3.0.0-alpha3](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=12310760&version=12328836) was released so while it is open source it also has quite an active community which develops it further and provides bug fixes.

Comment: I am considering PDFBox and planning to create a POC around this. Do you think of anything else other than this ?

Comment: Can't think of anything else because I was using this at two different companies. For Java it seems to me a defacto standard if you are not willing to pay for iText.